# Setroubleshoot dbus access error

Tags: d-bus

When running setroubleshootd in fedora, I get this error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.79" is not allowed
to own the service "org.fedoraProject.Setroubleshootd" due to security  
policies in the configuration file
```

Now I know this has something to do with the dbus policy, either in `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` or a file in `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/` or in `/etc/dbus-1/session.conf` or a file in `/etc/dbus-1/session.d/*`

But I have no idea what exactly the problem is, what file I need to look at. what policy I need to modify or how I am suposed to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Fedora 11, setroubleshootd is [not supposed to be running](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/selinux/2010-April/012453.html) in the background:

> setroubleshootd is now a dbus service.  It is supposed to be started
>   when and AVC arrives or you start the sealert browser.  It dies 10
>   seconds after the last connection/AVC arrival.

If you don't get desktop notifications, there might be other problem than the setroubleshootd not running all the time.